# I'd like to sometimes see the year in the x-axis in a HighStock chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a HighStock chart with the usual date/time on the x-axis. The chart might include multiple years of data.

When the user zooms in, HighCharts automatically formats the labels on the x-axis appropriately, showing month/year, or date/time, etc. It does a good job.

But when the user zooms in there is no indication of what year the data is they are looking at. See the following image:

[image]

It would be nice to show the year without having to make use of a formatter function (HighCharts is 99% there, why re-invent the wheel?). I guess this is as much a feature request as it is a question.

Comment: You should be able to use dateTimeLabelFormats for changing formats of your labels on zoom: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats

Comment: "would be nice to show the year without having to make use of a formatter function"

Comment: Thanks Gerry, however dateTimeLabelFormats is not exactly the same as labels.formatter function, inside this option you are only passing how you would like your xAxis to look and Highcharts will convert date formats for you.